# how to fetch all the records every minute from a sql table using Apache Flume

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I am trying to get all the data from sql table every minute using Flume.
Can someone please suggest what config changes needs to be done?

Configs :

```
agent.channels = ch1
agent.sinks = kafkaSink
agent.sources = sql-source
agent.channels.ch1.type = memory
agent.channels.ch1.capacity = 1000000
agent.sources.sql-source.channels = ch1
agent.sources.sql-source.type = org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource
# URL to connect to database
agent.sources.sql-source.connection.url = jdbc:sybase:Tds:abcServer:4500
# Database connection properties
agent.sources.sql-source.user = user
agent.sources.sql-source.password = XXXXXXX
agent.sources.sql-source.table = person
agent.sources.sql-source.columns.to.select = *
# Increment column properties
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.column.name = person_id
# Increment value is from you want to start taking data from tables (0 will import entire table)
agent.sources.sql-source.incremental.value = 0
# Query delay, each configured milisecond the query will be sent
agent.sources.sql-source.run.query.delay=1000
# Status file is used to save last readed row
agent.sources.sql-source.status.file.path = /dump/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin
agent.sources.sql-source.status.file.name = sql-source.status
```

Answer (score 1):

Change value of agent.sources.sql-source.run.query.delay to 60000..